# Section number disappears with tcolorbox

Tags: sectioning, tcolorbox

I'm having an issue working with *tcolorbox*. I'm using a *text marker* box (page 183 http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) and then I declare a new section but the number of the section disappears !

Here is the code for the box :

```
\tcbset{textmarker/.style={skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,breakable,parbox=true,boxrule=0mm,leftrule=5mm,rightrule=5mm,boxsep=0mm,arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,oversize}}
\newtcolorbox{orange}{textmarker,colback=DarkOrange!5!white,colframe=DarkOrange!75!yellow}
```

And here is the code itself :

```
    \item \texttt{CL\_OUT\_OF\_HOST\_MEMORY} s'il y a un échec d'allocation des ressources par l'hôte.
\end{itemize}
}
\end{orange}

\section{Modèle de mémoire}
\label{memory_model}

Le modèle de mémoire OpenCL garantit une cohérence mémoire entre les dispositifs par un partitionnement des données et une répartition des tâches dans différents work-items.
```

With a screenshot :

[image]

Do you guys know why it's doing this every time a section or chapter is declared right after that kind of boxes ?

Thanks in advance,

Marc

**EDIT :**
Here, I tried to reproduce the effect in a new document :

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\def\titlefont{\rmfamily}
\def\titleshape{\scshape}
\def\titlestyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}
\def\headerstyle{\titlefont\titleshape\bfseries}

\titleformat{\section}{\Large\headerstyle}{\bfseries\thesection.\ }{0pt}{\color{orange}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\tcbset{textmarker/.style={skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,breakable,parbox=true,boxrule=0mm,leftrule=5mm,rightrule=5mm,boxsep=0mm,arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,left=3mm,right=3mm,top=1mm,bottom=1mm,toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,oversize}}

\newtcolorbox{yellow}{textmarker,colback=yellow!5!white,colframe=yellow}
\newtcolorbox{orange}{textmarker,colback=orange!5!white,colframe=orange!75!yellow}

\section{Nice section}

\begin{orange}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus blandit convallis ipsum, vitae iaculis nisl ornare ac. Duis imperdiet tellus eget bibendum pellentesque. Praesent tincidunt mi ut eros varius, in condimentum elit porta. Donec mauris lacus, dapibus in elit id, condimentum efficitur diam. In dapibus lorem ac lorem facilisis congue. Quisque convallis sed nisl in placerat. Pellentesque eros magna, maximus sit amet arcu nec, tempor sodales metus. Integer eget venenatis lorem. Donec in volutpat sapien.

Integer pretium sagittis ante vitae dictum. Curabitur ut porttitor est. Nulla facilisi. Nulla porttitor rutrum ipsum ut hendrerit. Fusce commodo ligula non ex ullamcorper laoreet. Nam elit neque, imperdiet sed nibh sed, interdum commodo neque. Pellentesque tristique dui sed erat iaculis facilisis. Praesent maximus quis metus a euismod.

Sed aliquam arcu vel nisl porta fermentum. Nulla ornare quam et feugiat sodales. Pellentesque vel congue erat. Mauris sit amet tellus convallis, tempus nulla a, convallis justo. Pellentesque dignissim velit eget ligula scelerisque ultricies. Nullam quis urna purus. Nunc a rutrum justo. Nulla scelerisque augue quis iaculis consectetur. Aenean molestie dui purus, eget elementum mi luctus sed. Nam tristique purus purus, vel semper mauris aliquam sit amet. Nulla aliquet nisi ipsum, sit amet auctor odio sollicitudin a. Phasellus turpis odio, ultrices vitae augue quis, blandit dapibus est. Vivamus porta nulla vel felis tempus, non pharetra nunc ullamcorper. Vivamus consectetur lectus nisl. Ut eget scelerisque arcu. Maecenas erat diam, aliquam vel sapien at, sagittis aliquet orci.

Sed lorem nisi, finibus eu sagittis sit amet, finibus eget libero. Morbi sed porta massa. Donec lacus ligula, mattis eu auctor hendrerit, feugiat eu est. Vivamus vitae mattis velit, ac ullamcorper nisi. Praesent elit massa, tincidunt lacinia mauris eget, viverra sodales tellus. Etiam efficitur urna vel imperdiet convallis. Quisque ac mauris nisi. Etiam eu tempor nibh, non tempus magna. Nunc ac efficitur leo. Suspendisse rhoncus a dolor quis euismod. Donec congue odio felis, varius convallis ligula pharetra lobortis.

Mauris dignissim lectus quis nunc porta volutpat. Integer nisl lacus, accumsan in porttitor id, fermentum vel sapien. Suspendisse venenatis, urna sagittis varius convallis, felis eros egestas orci, eget vestibulum tellus lectus et arcu. Morbi nunc mi, iaculis nec auctor vitae, pulvinar quis lectus. Praesent efficitur nunc non orci efficitur, vel lobortis nibh interdum. In hendrerit mauris nunc, ac ullamcorper turpis consequat non. Donec in mollis lacus. Suspendisse tempor tellus eu lacus scelerisque tempus. Duis metus dui, aliquam eget lobortis eu, dictum quis lorem. In nec libero ultrices, elementum sapien ac, gravida orci. Fusce mauris sapien, imperdiet ac libero vel, vulputate mattis leo. Praesent tristique sagittis justo quis blandit. Nunc posuere tortor leo, sit amet imperdiet leo vehicula vitae. Nullam eget molestie tellus, consequat hendrerit risus.

Mauris feugiat et quam id placerat. Mauris faucibus quam pharetra tortor consequat tempus. Vestibulum eleifend blandit velit eu volutpat. Etiam maximus pellentesque lorem gravida imperdiet. Morbi viverra urna arcu, finibus pulvinar nisi accumsan eu. Suspendisse laoreet venenatis est, in fermentum ex hendrerit in. Nam eleifend massa molestie pharetra posuere. Fusce nec mauris non sem tincidunt volutpat et ac neque. Proin eu varius sapien. Curabitur finibus leo nec quam volutpat, et rutrum sapien bibendum. Morbi vitae neque et ex luctus vestibulum. Nullam sed vehicula orci.

Sed erat eros, convallis et tortor eu, sagittis facilisis orci. Aenean scelerisque molestie leo a molestie. Duis scelerisque sapien augue, a mollis nisi blandit eget. Proin gravida nibh nibh, at tristique purus vestibulum eget. Aliquam fringilla sem vel finibus pretium. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque bibendum placerat metus sit amet accumsan. Nulla at sapien a eros lacinia sollicitudin. Phasellus luctus, ipsum sit amet porttitor eleifend, felis lacus suscipit risus, vitae aliquam sapien erat at dolor. Aenean quis urna ipsum. Duis aliquam et ligula sed vestibulum. Nam molestie ipsum lorem, a ultrices metus tincidunt sagittis. Duis euismod placerat commodo. Ut massa nisl, rhoncus a placerat vel, ultricies eget lacus. Vivamus consectetur consectetur ligula sed laoreet. Donec iaculis, mauris sed tempus mattis, ligula lorem rhoncus metus, at posuere sapien augue in ante. 
\end{orange}

\section{No number section}
\end{document}
```

And then I realized that the problem occurs only if the text is that long that the box breaks into a new page !

(it is worth mentionning that it needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX)

[image]

LOGFILE : http://paste.awesom.eu/yfBG

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: As LaRiFaRi said your code is incomplete. After completing under my own criteria, it worked for me.but I need to see your code to be sure.

Comment: Sorry I didn't do that in the first place, now it's done !

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Works fine for me too. How current is your texsystem?

Comment: I used Texmaker (texlive) on Windows 7 with XeLaTeX to produce this issue with the full code I posted.

Comment: I have no problems with xelatex from texlive 2014 on win 7. Show the log-file of the minimal example.

Comment: I added the logfile generated by Texmaker, I'm using texlive 2014 on Windows 7 too but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: @Marc You should update your TeX system with `tlmgr`; for instance, `tcolorbox` is only version 3.04, while the current version is 3.50, released 2015/03/16.

Comment: No need to compile with XeLaTeX, I got two nice pages with pdftex. AND thank you for the nice example of this kind of tcolorbox, that's really useful.